# Android json utf8

Tags: android, json

Boa tarde! Tenho uma classe que importa dados json, mas alguns caracteres não são reconhecidos, tenho que aplicar utf8 neles, mas não estou conseguindo, abaixo a função que importa os dados.

```
public void carregarCategorias() {
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            categoria = new Categoria();
                            categoria.setIcone(obj.getString("icone"));
                            categoria.setCategoria(obj.getString("categoria"));
                            categoria.setEmpresas(obj.getString("empresas"));
                            categoriaList.add(categoria);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // Notificando adaptador lista sobre as alterações de dados
                    // Para que ele torna a exibição de lista com dados atualizados
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    itemClick();
}
```

Por favor, alguém me ajude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já enfrentei esse problema uma vez, e resolvi convertendo a string para bytes no padrão ISO-8859-1 e depois criando uma nova String. Criei um método que retorna a String em UTF-8:

```
public static RetornaStringUtf8JSon(JSONObject obj, String key) {
    return new String(obj.getString(key).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"); 
}
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069799/android-json-charset-utf-8-problems